# how can I find number of row and column from number of cell

Tags: matlab

Please tell me how can find number of row and column from number of cell. for example row and column of the 12th cell is 1 and 3. and also about 3D matrix

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by the 12th cell? What are the dimensions of your matrix? Do you actually mean a cell matrix (i.e. `{...}`) or are you just talking about the elements of a regular matrix? I would assume that you're looking to convert a linear index to a subscript index - but if that is the case I can't think of a matrix shape that would allow 12 to be (1,3), please explain where you get your numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be carefull with the concept of cells wich are a structure of their own in Matlab.

That being said, you are looking to convert linear indexes to subindexes, and that is done with the `ind2sub` function:

```
A=magic(4); %create 4x4 magic matrix

subidx=find(A==2); %subindex of the value 2, returns 5 

[i,j]=ind2sub(size(A),subidx)
```

returns

```
i =

     1


j =

     2
```

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my simple question

Comment: No probs, we all asked these simple questions once!

Comment: `format compact` could be used for a "compact" display of the output from code run. It's sort of my personal preference, so it's a suggestion really.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basics, not MatLab specific 12th cell would be rows of 9
NB the following assumes 0 based arrays, apparently Matlab is 1-based..
e.g

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 A B C D E F G H
```

so assuming you know the number of columns in a row

```
row = 12 / 9 ( = 1)
col = 12 % row ( = 3)  % is modulus operator i.e remainder after integer division
```

Comment: I think you've made two incorrect assumptions here. Firstly Matlab indexes from 1 and not 0. Secondly Matlab would count down the columns (i.e. column major) first and not across the rows. (Also modulo in Matlab is  `mod(,)`)

Comment: Will edit the answer, wasn't a matlab one just the basics of going from cell to row / column.